# Dynamically passing different objects to same method

Tags: java, parameter-passing, overriding

I have a method that does the same task for 4 different kind of classes when passed as parameters. Currently, I have to write that method 4 times for all 4 of those classes. Example:

```
doSomethingForClass1(MyClass1 myclass1, Address address);
doSomethingForClass2(MyClass2 myclass2, Address address);
doSomethingForClass3(MyClass3 myclass3, Address address);
doSomethingForClass4(MyClass4 myclass4, Address address);
```

All these methods are doing the same thing and returning the same object. How can I consolidate it into one method and pass different objects?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how the classes are related and what you are doing with them in the method. But either of polymorphism and/or generics should be of help to you here.

Answer (score 6):

If all 4 of your classes could implement the same interface, say, IMyClass, then you could have a single method.

```
doSomethingForClass1(IMyClass myclass, Address address);
```

Though this may not be possible or may not make sense for your application.  But, if this does make sense, also consider putting the method in the interface.  e.g.

```
   public interface IMyClass {
       public void doSomethingWithAnAddress(Address address);
   }
```

And then you code becomes even simpler,

```
myClass.doSomethingWithAnAddress(address);
```

p.s. you could also have a common abstract base class instead of the interface.

Comment: Since the first part of this answer follows all the other answers, why the downvote?  And the second part is a suggestiong to consider the Information Expert principal from [OOAD / GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_Expert).

Comment: @MasterCassim Just to check my sanity, I just looked at java.util.Collection, and not a single one of those methods is declared as public or abstract.  Are you arguing that I should leave out the "public" in the method declaration, and that this is actually important and significant???

Comment: You don't need the public here: public void doSomethingWithAnAddress(Address address); as interface methods are public abstract by default. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29

Comment: @MasterCassim Understood.  Mainly out of habit (and because co-workers do the same) I've always put in the redundant "public".  I think it occasioannly helps late at night when you start forgetting if the code is inside a class or an interface.  (Or there are a lot of inner classes / inner interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to have your MyClassX classes all extend from the same super class or interface, and then create a method that uses a parameter of the super class or interface -- in other words have a super *type*.

```
doSomethingForClass(MySuperType superType, Address address) {
    // ...
}
```

and have your classes share an interface

```
class MyClass1 implements MySuperType {
    //....
}
```

and,...

```
class MyClass2 implements MySuperType {
    //....
}
```

etc...

For this to work, the `doSomethingForClass(...)` method can only call the methods that are defined within the interface.

Answer (score 1):

If they are doing the same thing, how come they accept *completely* different objects? If by "*doing the same thing*" you mean "*invoking exactly the same methods*", looks like all of the `MyClass?` types should have a common interface/superclass, gathering all common methods:

```
public MyClass1 implements MyClass {/*...*/}
public MyClass2 implements MyClass {/*...*/}
public MyClass3 implements MyClass {/*...*/}
public MyClass4 implements MyClass {/*...*/}
```

Now taking advantage of polymorphism:

```
doSomethingForClass(MyClass myclass, Address address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as you'll note from the comments, we strongly dissuade the practices used in my code example, particularly as a beginner.  It's still here for your reference, however.

I think you want to explore inheritance and polymorphism.  Alternatively, I guess an ugly solution would be to 'elevate' your MyClass argument to Object, then something like:

```
myMethod(Object myClass, Address address){
    if(myClass instanceof MyClass1){
        MyClass1 mc = (MyClass1) myClass;
        doStuff();
    }
    else if(myClass instanceof MyClass2){
        MyClass2 mc = (MyClass2) myClass;
        doStuff();
    }
    else if(myClass instanceof MyClass3){
        MyClass3 mc = (MyClass3) myClass;
        doStuff();
    }
    else if(myClass instanceof MyClass4){
        MyClass4 mc = (MyClass4) myClass;
        doStuff();
    }
    else panic();
}
```

That would at least solve the consolidate part.  Inheritance and polymorphism would be much sexier though.

Comment: Please don't recommend the use of the instanceOf anti-pattern. This is what we use OOPs to avoid.

Comment: That's harsh - it wasn't a recommendation, hence my emphasis on inheritance and polymorphism. I was merely making the suggestion, should anyone find it of use.

Comment: It's not a recommendation? Shoot, you give a code example of it, one that should be removed as it shouldn't even be a suggestion. It's just plain wrong.

Comment: Wrong? I think that's for the implementer and compiler to decide.

Comment: @c24w: based on our advice. And since they're usually new at this, they can't distinguish between good and bad advice, otherwise they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place, and which is why we shouldn't be giving bad advice. And again, your advice here is bad.

Comment: Down-vote removed, but I would ask that you edit your post to more strongly dissuade the op from using your code suggestion. Again, it's not something we want to promulgate.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform the same operation on those 4 classes, with exactly the same method calls, ... those classes probably implement the same interface or extend from the same superclass. In that case, you can program against that interface/abstract class

```
doSomething( Interface myClass, Address address);
```